JIS or ISO standard on Merlin Road 92 Titanium bottom bracket spindle?
My early 90s Merlin road frame got that titanium spindle and I wonder whether it is JIS or ISO square tapered. According to the catalogue the name of the bottom bracket is "Beta-C"

Does this answer your question? How can I tell the difference between a J.I.S. and ISO square taper bottom bracket?

This website suggest that it's JIS, you have to scroll down to sixth comment in the post: https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/1026144-bottom-bottom-bracket-1990s-merlin-mountain-frame.html
